# Using <span class="math-tex"> while parsing HTML in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, html-react-parser

I'm trying to parse HTML containing `<span class="math-tex">` to render math equations in react, from an existing database.

From what I've found the `<span class="math-tex">` element is from a CKEditor widget, but I can't figure out how to use it with React and html-react-parser.

I've tried using

```
npm install ckeditor4-react
```

and putting

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>
```

into my index.html but it doesn't seem to work.

The goal is to use

```
Parser("some HTML containing <span class="math-tex"> elements")
```

to display equations on my react app

Thanks for any pointers you have.

Comment: Can you just render the html with [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think my problem was that I needed to use the span element within the CKEditor to be picked up.